# Not able to get executable path for process id 4 (ntoskrnl.exe)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, getmodulefilename

I have been trying to obtain the executable path by enumerating all processes. I used both **GetModuleFileNameExA** and **QueryFullProcessImageNameA** to obtain the path of the executables.

It works for almost everything except few like **ntoskrnl.exe** (System, **Process id: 4**). When I use these methods, the **HANDLE** that's obtained is **NOT NULL** but the functions **fail**.

GetLastError turns out to be **31**

Is there any problem with the code or any workaround has to be done? 
NOTE: My EXE is a 32-bit EXE and I have a 64 bit OS. Does this have anything to do with it?

```
INT32 GetFileNameAndPath(DWORD processId,string &filePath,string &fileName)
{
CHAR path[MAX_PATH];
DWORD size=MAX_PATH;
smatch match;

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION,FALSE,processId);

if(hProcess != NULL)
{
    regex regx("[^\\\\]+$");

    if(GetModuleFileNameExA(hProcess,NULL,path,size) != 0)
    {
        filePath = path;

        if(regex_search(filePath,match,regx))
            fileName = match.str();
    }
    else if(QueryFullProcessImageNameA(hProcess,0,path,&size) != 0)
    {
        filePath = path;

        if(regex_search(filePath,match,regx))
            fileName = match.str();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<GetLastError();
    }
}

CloseHandle(hProcess);

return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The answer is that you cannot obtain the path of ntoskrnl.exe. I was wondering how task manager does it. I found it after checking it for hours! :P (Shouldn't have taken that much).

[Task Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb8Xg.jpg)

If you see that screenshot you can see that the process **System's Image path name** was **C:\WINDOWS** whereas for conhost.exe it was C:\Windows.

Even windows have hardcoded for that Exe. They have hardcoded it as **%Systemroot%\system32\ntoskrnl.exe**. Only when you expand Systemroot you get the value as **C:\WINDOWS**. When you do with API such as GetModuleFileNameEx you get the path as **C:\Windows**. So technically there isn't a way. And by my assumption, due to security reasons they didn't allow any user to get the path of the Exe.

Comment: This has nothing to do with security.

Comment: @Keshav It's insane to me that people are downvoting here. Seriously, this community needs rules and guidelines, of course, to achieve and maintain a desired structure. But hostility isn't up on that list. No apparent reason this should be downvoted. Ego of one of the commentators notwithstanding...

Comment: i simply change this hardcode string in memory and got another name in ui - so this is really hardcoded

Comment: @Kehsav this is not about security. Otherwise system process with correct privileges would see it. The thing is, `ntoskrnl.exe` is not an actual executable image. The bootloader copies it to memory and jumps to it. It *actually* has no image in the `GetModuleFileName` sense, because it was never loaded as a “module”. With appropriate permissions, you should even be able to delete the file, because it should not be in use.

Comment: Alright, I get it. It is not due to security. And like you said @SkepticalEmpiricist I don't know why I'm getting a downvote for the post! :D

Thank you all anyway! :D

Comment: @spectras And also if you have observed that ntoskrnl.exe runs as two processes with both different name (Registry and System). Do you have any idea how it is happening? As far as I've seen the Exe name is the name of process. Both system and Registry point out to the same exe (Ntoskrnl.exe)